# Get Wikipedia Article excluding ones with Title in a list

Tags: javascript, wikipedia-api

So I want to get a random Wikipedia Article but I don't want to grab the ones where the title or category is in a specific list I have (for bad word filtering).

I am currently using javascript and I'm not too familiar with the Wikipedia API but I have the query string to generate a random article and grab the extract but I'm not too sure on how to do the excluding.  I didn't see anything in the documentation or even searching Google on how to do that.

The code is working and is fetching random articles but I need to filter them.

My actual javascript code that does the fetching

```
if (tempscript) return;
        if (!isRetry) {
            attempts = 0;
            minchars = minimumCharacters;
            maxchars = maximumCharacters;
            button.disabled = true;
            button.style.cursor = "wait";
        }
        tempscript = document.createElement("script");
        tempscript.type = "text/javascript";
        tempscript.id = "tempscript";
        tempscript.src = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" + "?action=query&generator=random&prop=extracts" + "&exchars=" + maxchars + "&format=json&callback=onComplete&requestid=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999).toString();
        document.body.appendChild(tempscript);
```

Comment: Are you saying this can't be done?

Comment: no, but it can't be done in the way you're thinking off. wiki doesn't provide a "random but" feature. Your chances of badness are slim, so an occasional double-load is a small price to pay to implement such functionality if you need it. if you give your code a name by putting it in a function, it will be super easy to fire again from your word scrubber routine.

Comment: So basically you're saying go the fetch and check the title for instance and if the title contains a word inside my word filter than fetch a new one?

Comment: that's exactly what i'm saying.

Comment: Great, guess that's what I'll have to do then :)...Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your url to also inclide `categories` in your `prop`, and then set the `cllimit` to the maximum of 500:

```
tempscript.src = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" + "?action=query&generator=random&prop=categories|extracts&cllimit=500&exchars=" + maxchars + "&format=json&callback=onComplete&requestid=" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999).toString();
```

Then, if the page has categories, it will list them in the returned JSON object.

In your callback function, you will then need the following:

```
var badArticles = ['Poop', 'Pee', 'Underpants'],
    badCategories = ['Images of poop', 'Images of pee', 'Images of underpants'],
    page = response.query.pages;
for (var i in page) {
    page = page[i]; // `i` will be the pageid in this loop
    break; // you don't want the loop to continue within the new `page` object
}

//exit callback when pagename is in bad articles list 
if (badArticles.indexOf(page.title) !== -1) return false;

if (page.categories) {
    for (var i=0;i<page.categories.length;i++) {

        //exit callback when pagename has a category in bad categories list
        if (badCategories.indexOf(page.categories[i].title)) return false;

    }
}
```

That should work. I did not personally test it, but I would expect that to work, based on the format of the MediaWiki API's response. If that doesn't work, please leave a comment.